# How do I integrate Byobu's copy-buffer with the X clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, gnu-screen, byobu

I want to be able to copy and paste between Byobu and Firefox without having to use a mouse. I could write the copy buffer to a file and open that file with Gedit but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: What is byobu's copy buffer?

Comment: ctrl+A+[ , then spacebars to mark the beginning and end of the selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [XSel](http://www.vergenet.net/%7Econrad/software/xsel/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xsel)) to insert the text into the X selection buffer:

```
echo "paste your buffer from byobu/screen here" | xsel
```

Use [`-b`/`--clipboard`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xsel.1x.html) to copy to CLIPBOARD selection instead of PRIMARY.

Comment: That's really manual.