# How to copy command console text?

Tags: console, clipboard

I have used the wpa_passphrase command and I get something like this:

> network={  ssid="blahblah"
>       #psk="moreblahblah"     psk=d5e532ecca53ea963e5b3b5521bb3682c53fcf5b6d55f15622027145c795b661 }

I need to copy that "psk=[long string]" to my wpa_supplicant.conf file.  How can I select it in order to copy it?  And then what command do I use to copy it?  Such that in my favourite text editor I can press a paste command to paste it?  (ps. I don't have a mouse )

Answer (score 24):

if you have a touchpad though, highlight the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy ...

the following resources describe how to copy/paste using keyboard only -- screen/byobu:

[How do I integrate Byobu's copy-buffer with the X clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33789/how-do-i-integrate-byobus-copy-buffer-with-that-of-the-systems)

http://www.samsarin.com/blog/2007/03/11/gnu-screen-working-with-the-scrollback-buffer/

> #### Copy and Paste in Scrollback mode (screen/byobu)
>
> - Enter scrollback mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> or in byobu also <kbd>F7</kbd>
> - Move the cursor to the start of the text you want to copy, hit <kbd>spacebar</kbd>
> - Move the cursor to the end of the text you want to copy and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
> - To paste text, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: This information isn't quite right for byobu. Copy in byobu is Spacebar then Enter, per the [byobu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/byobu.1.html#contenttoc8). Differs slightly from screen in that way. I only mention it here because this post happens to rank very highly on google for "copy/paste in byobu".

Comment: Works like a charm to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
wpa_passphrase | awk '/psk/ {print $4}' >> wpa.supplicant.conf
```

Command should take out the "psk=d5e532ecca53ea963e5b3b5521bb3682c53fcf5b6d55f15622027145c795b661" part and copy it to the end of your wpa.supplicant.conf file. Try changing `$4` to `$3` or `$2` if you don't get the right part of the wpa_passphrase command.

Answer (score 1):

May be not perfect but a workaround. May be you could write the output in a file then go into the file remove unnecessary text and using `cat` you could append it to wpa_supplicant.conf

Basically your workflow would be:

`command > rough`

`nano rough` here delete the unnecessary text and keep just the necessary ones i.e psk

`sudo sh -c "cat rough >> wpa_supplicant.conf"`

Or may be you could use vim to yank the required text choosing it in visual mode.

P.S. Someone with good knowledge of sed would give you a easier solution than this I think.

Comment: the `sudo sh ...` command could be written as: `cat rough | sudo tee -a wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn And `cat rough |` could be replaced with `< rough`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the most common way to do this would be to use a mouse or other pointing device (such as a touchpad). Although it's somewhat excentric, it's possible to copy text without a mouse. (You may of course have a valid reason not use a pointing device.) Check out `xclip`, as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility#11930). Thus you could use:

```
wpa_passphrase | xclip -sel clip
```

Answer (score 0):

The next sed command will fetch the key (which consists of characters from the hexadecimal set) from the output of `wpa_passphrase` and put it in a temporary file `pass`.

```
wpa_passphrase | sed 's/.*psk=\([0-9a-f]*\).*/\1/' > pass
```

As you do not have a mouse, you cannot just select and copy it. We'll use the `nano` texteditor for inserting this pass:

```
nano wpa_suppliciant.conf
```

Move to your desired location using your arrow keys and press <kbd>Insert</kbd>. Enter the name of the file you've just created, `pass`, followed by an Enter. Quit & save the result by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and confirm it by entering <kbd>Y</kbd> followed by an <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a keybinding in byobu to be able to send the text selected in byobu's buffer into the X clipboard.

Add the following to `~/.byobu/keybindings`

```
# Add cool line to make copying to x clipboard possible.
# This binds C-a b to copy screen's copy buffer to the system clipboard.
bind b eval writebuf 'exec /bin/sh -c "xsel -i < $BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen"'
```

Then after using the usual F7, move, space to start select, move, enter to save to buffrer, then you can use `C-a b` (Ctrl-a, then b) to save it to the clipboard

(Based on https://dodoincfedora.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/integrating-byobuscreens-copy-buffer-with-xgnome-clipboard/)