# Better terminal for Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, gnome-terminal

Please suggest a terminal application for Ubuntu desktop which meets the following requirements:

1. Paste via Right Mouse Click  (without showing the context menu)
2. Copy via Mouse selection.
3. Solarized color scheme.

With current one "GNOME Terminal v3.6.0" it is not possible.
Or suggest a way to improve Gnome Terminal.

P.S. Why I dislike the "selection buffer" behavior. For example, I have in a text editor the word "command" and in terminal window command `ls -la` and I want to replace that word in Text Editor onto the command from terminal.

The selection buffer is not suitable in that case because when you will select "command" in the text editor to replace it you will have "command" in "selection buffer". So you will paste "command" instead of "command" :). You could only select `ls -la` and paste it after "command" via Middle Mouse Click and remove "command" after it. Too many clicks.

That is why I want to use "Clipboard" for that instead of "selection buffer".

Select with mouse -> Right Mouse Click -> Select in Context Menu Copy -> Left Mouse Click on that menu item - also too much clicks.

Comment: It is actually possible to copy and paste using mouse in gnome-terminal 3.6. Please elaborate, if you mean something else.

Comment: @green7 yes. it is possible. via "selection buffer" But I want via "Clipboard" and using RMC instead of MMC. If there is no terminal emulator with such functionality. I'll try to use MMC. Or will code.

Comment: I can do it in my computer. What doesn't work is CTRL+C, as this has a special meaning in the terminal. You can use SHIFT+CTRL+C to copy text or select it, rigth click and select copy.

Comment: @denys Have you tried clipboard managers, like `clipit`? You can get it from Software Center.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't be able to configure all this in Gnome terminal

Answer (score 48):

**GNOME Terminal** has the above functionalities.

---

In case you didn't know, in most terminal emulators:

- Copy text: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + c</kbd>
- Past text: <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + v</kbd>

### Have a look at these great alternatives

#### [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda)

Simple, GTK+ pop-up terminal - https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda

[image: Tilda terminal emulator sreenshot]
[image: Install via the software center]

#### [Guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake)

GTK+ popup terminal. Great multi-monitor support. - https://github.com/Guake/guake

[image: Guake sreenshot]
[image: Install via the software center]

Check out [Yakuake](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/yakuake/) for a Qt/KDE alternative.

#### [Terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology)

Feature rich terminal using the EFL toolkit. https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology

[image: Terminology sreenshot]

[WebUpd8 article about Terminology](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/terminology-more-than-terminal-emulator.html)

Answer (score 30):

There is one more terminal application you can install & the includes with many features . It's named as terminator.

you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

in your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Guake is a GREAT emulator. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

Comment: why the vote down?

Comment: @Seth , Ryan, and black sensei, can you explain a little bit about `guake` features, please?

Comment: I like guake.. nice terminal

Comment: @Ryan: Why are you pleased with it, yet not a fan personally?

Comment: Not the nicest name though; "Guake"... ugh.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is a pretty neat combination:

- **Terminal emulator**: Any: Konsole, GNOME/XFCE4 emulator, [Alacritty](https://alacritty.org/), [wezterm](https://github.com/wez/wezterm/issues/1751), <strike>[kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/faq/#i-am-using-tmux-and-have-a-problem)</strike>..
- **Global shortcut** (necessary on Wayland): On GNOME, [quake-mode](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1411/quake-mode/)
- **Multiplexer**: [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) with [tmux-plugins](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/) ([list](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/list)) or [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) (friendly tmux wrapper)
- **More**: zsh + [oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) + themes + plugins.

#### Alacritty + quake-mode + Byobu with/or tmux

As I said <sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355145/209677) [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/898953/349837) [3](https://askubuntu.com/a/865822/349837)</sup>, I'm a happy user of [Alacritty](https://alacritty.org/) with [Byobu](http://byobu.co/) inside it, which by default use `tmux` ([better than `screen`](https://superuser.com/a/236160/500826)).

1. [Install Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and byobu: `sudo apt install alacritty byobu` (or with dependencies and `cargo install alacritty`, you can remove `cargo  cmake cmake-data librhash0 libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev` afterward).
2. On GNOME: [Install quake-mode](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1411/quake-mode/) or any way to enable a global shortcut (for the time being mandatory on Wayland). Alacritty currently doesn't offer a `--toggle`/`--quake` option. Configure it to run the terminal with the global shortcut of your choice (for eg <kbd>F12</kbd>).

   Wayland didn't allow applications registering global shortcuts/hotkeys (security reasons, control a not focused app). The only apps working are the old ones running over xwayland.
   **Update**: Now we have XDG Desktop Portals (xdg-desktop-portals) for global shortcuts. Already implemented on KDE, but [not on GNOME](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/47).
3. Setup Alacritty on `~/.config/alacritty.yml`:

   ```yml
   window:
     opacity: 0.8
     # Or Windowed
     startup_mode: Fullscreen
   key_bindings:
     - { key: F11, action: ToggleFullscreen }
   shell:
     program: /usr/bin/byobu
   ```
4. To hide it from taskbar (validate syntax with `desktop-file-edit`):

   ```sh
   # WIP, sometimes doesn't work
   Exec=sh -c "~/.local/bin/alacritty & sleep 1;/usr/bin/wmctrl -x -r Alacritty.Alacritty -b add,skip_taskbar"
   ```

Also,

- I changed the local byobu/tmux escape sequence (<kbd>F9</kbd>) to <kbd>Ctrl + h</kbd> so it doesn't interfere with tmux on a remote server.
- Other byobu-related suggestions:

  - Learn byobu's shortcuts with <kbd>Shift + F1</kbd>,  [this excellent screencast](https://www.byobu.org/) or [this great cheat-sheet](https://gist.github.com/jshaw/5255721).
  - Learn available byobu terminal commands with `apropos byobu`, like `byobu-config` (configuration utility).

    - By default, byobu uses `tmux` as backend (you can use `tmux` shortcuts!). If you hate yourself, change it with `byobu-select-backend`.
  - To use fn keys on Midnight Commander, use <kbd>Alt + Nº</kbd> or <kbd>Shift + F12</kbd> to disable byobu F-keys.
- [tdrop](https://github.com/noctuid/tdrop) (*A Glorified WM-Independent Dropdown Creator*) now [seems to work on Wayland](https://github.com/noctuid/tdrop/issues/341). Also, [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/) seems incompatible.

#### zsh + oh-my-zsh + themes + plugins

Just that would be total happiness, but you can also:

- [**Install zsh**](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Installing-ZSH) (`sudo apt install zsh`) and [switch shell from `bash` on Byobu](https://askubuntu.com/a/961806/349837), and/or `chsh -s $(which zsh)` (making ZSH the Default Shell; require logut).
- Common tweaks

  - [Stop zsh from eating spaces before pipe](https://superuser.com/a/613817/500826): `ZLE_REMOVE_SUFFIX_CHARS=""`.
- [**Install oh-my-zsh**](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) ("plugin" manager, steroids for zsh; others are [antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen), [zplug](https://github.com/zplug/zplug) and [zim](https://zimfw.sh)):

  ```
  sudo apt install curl && sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
  ```
- `zsh` with oh-my-zsh becomes very powerful and beautiful with plugins and themes.

  - [**Plugins**](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins-Overview) I like (check the [awesome list](https://project-awesome.org/unixorn/awesome-zsh-plugins#plugins); keep in mind some of them might make your prompt slower):

    - Productivity: **`z`** [`zsh-autosuggestions`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) `colored-man-pages` `command-not-found` `extract` `zsh-history-substring-search` `pass` `taskwarrior` `web-search` `fzf`.
      [safe-paste](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste) (bracketed paste mode, [for safety](https://youtu.be/9DgQqDnYNyQ?t=544)) is enabled by default.
    - Build tools: `docker` `git` `github`
  - [**Themes**](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes)/prompts I like: [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/External-themes#powerlevel10k) ([homepage](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k)) agnoster, awesomepanda, gallois and [spaceship](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/getting-started/).

To install powerlevel10k:

1. Install the recommended font. Optional but highly recommended.

   ```sh
   wget --no-clobber --directory-prefix ~/.local/share/fonts/ https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/raw/master/MesloLGS%20NF%20Regular.ttf https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/raw/master/MesloLGS%20NF%20Bold.ttf https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/raw/master/MesloLGS%20NF%20Italic.ttf https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k-media/raw/master/MesloLGS%20NF%20Bold%20Italic.ttf
   fc-cache -f -v  # maybe not necessary
   ```

   Add to `~/.config/alacritty.yml`

   ```yaml
   font:
     normal:
       family: "MesloLGS NF"
   ```
2. Install Powerlevel10k itself.

   ```
   git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/themes/powerlevel10k
   ```

   Set `ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"` in `~/.zshrc`.
3. Restart Zsh with `exec zsh`.
4. Type `p10k configure` if the configuration wizard doesn't start automatically.

### See also

- [Starship](https://starship.rs/): *The minimal, blazing-fast, and infinitely customizable prompt for any shell!*. Similar to what you'll get with some zsh's plugins/themes. Alternative to powerlevel10k.
- [CLI improved](https://remysharp.com/2018/08/23/cli-improved): Better alternatives to common CLI programs.
- Test your terminal setup with [this *test drive*](https://hellricer.github.io/2019/10/05/test-drive-your-terminal.html).
- Other tools

  - [Navi](https://github.com/denisidoro/navi): *An interactive cheatsheet tool for the command-line*
  - [cheat](https://github.com/cheat/cheat) / [tldr](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr): *allows you to create and view interactive cheatsheets on the command-line* / *Collaborative cheatsheets for console commands*

Comment: This is the one I was looking for. I went through this, and it was a hell of a ride! Thank you for such a complete and detailed yet concise answer, accompanied with the necessary links.

Answer (score 1):

In any circumstance, I would suggest Simple Terminal (completely customizable look. Cozy and good-looking.) and I3WM. I3WM is cozy, but you must know what to look for. I3 is a dual-boot. It is a window manager that enhances performance and accessibility of you Linux distribution. Ubuntu 18.04 has the files for it pre-downloaded. To install it,`sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install i3`. If this does not work, try

```
$ /usr/lib/apt/apt-helper download-file http://dl.bintray.com/i3/i3-autobuild-ubuntu/pool/main/i/i3-autobuild-keyring/i3-autobuild-keyring_2016.10.01_all.deb keyring.deb SHA256:460e8c7f67a6ae7c3996cc8a5915548fe2fee9637b1653353ec62b954978d844
$ sudo apt install ./keyring.deb
$ sudo echo 'deb http://dl.bintray.com/i3/i3-autobuild-ubuntu bionic main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i3-autobuild.list
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install i3
```

---

Now for Simple Terminal (ST)

You can download the files for ST from https://st.suckless.org/. To install: click on the Archive Manager. Choose the ST file that you have downloaded. Now click unpack. Then, go to your terminal (the GNOME one.) and CD to it with `cd /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktp/st-0.8.2`. Then, install it with `xdg-open INSTALL`. Fianlly,

```
./configure
make
sudo make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

For Copy and paste you can do it even without a mouse
to do this:

- Copy: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
- Paste: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

And I recommend you to use terminator and then install "Oh my zsh" on it
it will make your terminal better and beautiful and with installing packages on it, it'll give you nice features like auto-completion and...
for downloading terminator :

```
sudo apt install terminator
```

and for installing zsh :

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

Build from source for newer versions: (Firstly, download `build-zsh.sh`)

```
chmod +x build-zsh.sh
./build-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In a default bash configuration, you can yank text and place it back on the shell without needing the mouse.

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>: yanks text from just before the cursor to the beginning of the line (the man page calls the backspace "rubout")
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: kill text from the cursor to the end of the line
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>:  places yanked text back onto the shell

Have a look at the man page for `readline`. It's got a lot of neat keyboard shortcuts.