# Is there any user friendly alternative to screen?

Tags: command-line, server, software-recommendation, gnu-screen

I am running **Ubuntu Server** and want to have multiple terminals.
Screen works fine but..it is not user friendly. I mean..after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you get no notification of you being in command mode, in order to display terminals you have to enter <kbd>"</kbd> which is not friendly at all (on my keyboard it is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), and so on..

I looked at byobu but it seems bugged: the cpu status lines keep increasing downside up and eventually cover my screen..but overall I still don't like it much.

I was searching for something with nano's graphic..with bottom part of the screen filled with instruction/status and upper part, of course, my current terminal.

Does something like that exist? Or, alternatively, can you help me fix the byobu bug?

Comment: "user friendly" is rather subjective ;) "screen" indeed has it flaws but I do not consider it "user unfriendly" ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**Tmux**](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) is a rewrite of GNU Screen, tmux offers a variety of improvements. Some of the most important include a client-server model, which allows you to connect to a tmux session from multiple locations, and a cleaner configuration file format. Check out tmux’s FAQ to discover a list of ways it differs from GNU Screen.

Use this command to install tmux on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

[How to on howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/114582/2-alternatives-to-gnu-screen-for-linux-terminal-multitasking/). That link also has something on **Dvtm & Dtach** (Dvtm is a console multiplexer inspired by tiling window managers, and dtach adds the ability to detach from and reattach to dvtm sessions).

Answer (score 18):

I wrote a more extended answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038860/349837).

### [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) with/or tmux

I think **byobu** is a more friendly alternative. It uses tmux as backend, so you have friendly byobu shortcuts, and also [tmux ones](https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/) (by default <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd>, you can change it with <kbd>F9</kbd> or [`byobu-config`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/byobu-config.1.html)).

[From its site](https://www.byobu.org/) (see also there the excellent screencast):

> Byobu is a GPLv3 open source text-based window manager and terminal multiplexer. It was originally designed to provide elegant enhancements to the otherwise functional, plain, practical GNU Screen, for the Ubuntu server distribution. Byobu now includes an enhanced profiles, convenient keybindings, configuration utilities, and toggle-able system status notifications for both the GNU Screen window manager and the more modern Tmux terminal multiplexer, and works on most Linux, BSD, and Mac distributions.

Install it with

```
sudo apt install byobu
```

Probably tmux could be tuned (with [plugins](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/) like [sensible](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible)) to be much more friendly.

A screenshot using [`hollywood`](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/12/hollywood-technodrama.html):

[image: screenshot]

[Here is](http://www.howtogeek.com/58487/how-to-easily-multitask-in-a-linux-terminal-with-byobu/) also a howtogeek article about it.

I use it with [Alacritty](https://alacritty.org/) (and [more](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038860/349837)) in full-screen. Not another window: Just there at <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Indeed. Byobu is a combination of screen and tmux but actually usable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Screenie](https://sourceforge.net/projects/screenie/)

From the [Man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/screenie.1.html):

> screenie is a small and lightweight screen(1) wrapper designed to
> simplify session selection on a system with multiple screen sessions.
> screenie provides simple interactive menu to select the existing
> screen session or to create a new one.

Entering `screenie` by itself starts it in the interactive mode and shows this menu:

```
screenie - terminal screen-session handler

 a) new session
 q) quit

 A parameter character can be appended to session selection:
   'x' to attach selected session with 'screen -x' command,
   'd' to attach selected session with 'screen -rd' command.

select:
```

Then it walks you through creating a new background session. You have to name your session (`test` below) and you can leave `job:` blank. If there are any background sessions running `screenie` lists them in its menu:

```
screenie - terminal screen-session handler

 1) 105970.test (06/10/2022 02:22:21 PM)

 a) new session
 q) quit

 A parameter character can be appended to session selection:
   'x' to attach selected session with 'screen -x' command,
   'd' to attach selected session with 'screen -rd' command.

select:
```

Selecting the index number before the background session, such as `1` will open that session.

Detach from `screen` by pressiing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd>, and you will be back in the `screenie` interactive menu.

Then you can leave `screenie` by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When you want to return to the background sessions again, enter `screenie` again in the terminal to see the menu again.

Hope this helps