# Input two commands to a new terminal?

Tags: command-line

Is there a way I can input these two commands into a new terminal at the same time?

```
( konsole -e sudo nethogs 
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 )
```

Comment: Could you add some more context? What are you trying to accomplish by running these commands "at the same time"?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want to do with `konsole` is the following:

```
$ konsole -e "sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1; sudo nethogs" --noclose --hold
```

This will invoke `konsole` and then run commands within it, `-e`. In this case we're running the 2 `sudo` commands and we're using the `--noclose` & `--hold` to tell `konsole` to keep the window open while these run.

Comment: root@MO-HP-EliteBook-8560p:/home/mo# konsole -e "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get update" --noclose --hold QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' root@MO-HP-EliteBook-

Comment: @mo97 - I cannot tell from what you posted, is it still not working?

Comment: @mo97 - you might want to try using `konsole -e "sudo whoami; sudo whoami" --noclose --hold` to see what the issue might be more easily.

Comment: Done everything you say .. This is the result ..
 QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

Comment: @mo97, You can also test what happens with the following command line, `konsole -e "sudo whoami; sudo whoami;bash"` -- The final `bash` will make the `konsole` window stay instead of close immediately after finishing the previous commands.

Comment: @slm Open the window and then ask for the password and then close it

Comment: @m097 - I dug this up from the Unix & Linux site with the same error you're encountering. Can you try using `gksudo` instead of `sudo`? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382789/qstandardpaths-xdg-runtime-dir-not-set-defaulting-to-tmp-runtime-root-when

Answer (score 0):

To send several commands to different terminals simultaneously one easy way could be with [byobu](https://askubuntu.com/a/865822/349837):

Press <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd> to vertical split, then <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd>:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]