# How to make zsh in byobu to be a login shell?

Tags: byobu, zsh

Long story short, I have a zsh setup, and I am using gnome terminal. I recently installed [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) and enabled it.

Now when I start a new terminal and Byobu comes up, my shell is not a login shell.

I tried `set -g` as suggested in a different question, but it did not help.

Comment: Have you tried either [chsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) or editing the /etc/passwd file to use zsh for your user?

Comment: What is the value of the SHELL environment value?  I recommend setting that.

Answer (score 3):

Add to `~.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-shell /bin/zsh
set -g default-command /bin/zsh
```

If using `tmux` as backend, else `.screenrc`.

[Source](http://ichimusai.org/configure-zsh-in-byobu/).

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the the same answer and finally I succeed by define ZSH as my default SH :
*not sure those command was useful but just in case*

```
# set -g default-shell /usr/bin/zsh
# set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

and after I installed byobu :

```
# sudo apt-get install byobu -y
```

and enable it into a ZSH session with the command :

`# byobu-enable`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu

Comment: I changed from bash to zsh when I already had byobu enabled, but after switching I just needed to run byobu-enable. I have not run the set -g commands and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered five years ago, but it turns out there's a simpler way to set ZSH as your default shell in byobu. Per [this Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/byobu/+question/96191), if you simply rename/remove the .byobu folder, it will create a new one based on the shell you're currently using.

The provided commands are:

```
mkdir $HOME/byobu_backup
mv $HOME/.screenrc $HOME/.byobu $HOME/byobu_backup
```