# Show/hide gnome terminal by a keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcut-keys

I need somehow to bind a key to open a gnome-terminal by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and hiding it by pressing same button. When I hide it and press <kbd>F12</kbd> again, I don't a want new terminal to be opened. I just need the previous one.

PS.: The behaviour should be just as in `guake` terminal, but `neovim` does not properly work on my system.

Comment: You may be able to use `xdotool` for this, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: I dont know if gnome terminal can work in such way, but I know that Terminator https://gnometerminator.blogspot.nl/p/introduction.html can.

Comment: @ipeacocks  How?

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038860/349837) (_See also_ section) I mention some alternatives