# How do I get my Guake terminal to look as fancy as this screenshot?

Tags: command-line, guake, tabs

I saw this screenshot from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281675/better-terminal-for-ubuntu/281736) post, and was curious as to how they got their Guake environment to have what looks like 3 split tabs. Any suggestions on how to do this? Are they running `tmux` on top of Guake or something of the sort?

[image]

Comment: It's not the guake terminal, instead `htop`, `zsh` maybe with `oh-my-zsh` addons

Comment: @Anwar How do you know is not Guake? Could be Guake without tabs, with `screen`, with `zsh` with [agnoster theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes). Great combination, I prefer `byobu` with `tmux` as backend thus.

Comment: @PabloBianchi Ask him

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see in the screenshot is couple apps, actually.  Tripple split is done by `screen` as suggested by the name in lower right corner in the screenshot and the process manager in top split is  `htop`.

I personally would recommend byobu instead of just `screen`, since that has fancier interface showing clock, ip address, and other stats. All the apps are installable via `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE-NAME`

Here's for instance what can be done witih Byobu. Similar layout:

[image]

Comment: You forgot those arrow-symbols in the prompt? Those are from powerline patched fonts. Maybe the terminal was using `zsh` shell. And the font is inconsolata

Comment: Byobu sits on top of `tmux` or `screen`, it use one of them as backend. By default (luckily) uses `tmux`. Take a look [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038860/349837).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Yep, that I know. Nice answer btw