# Jump to the Open Terminal Window

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, wayland

I've always got a terminal window open in my Ubuntu GNOME Wayland session. I know `Ctrl+Alt+T` is a keyboard shortcut to open a *new* terminal window. But how do I create a keyboard shortcut to jump to the currently open GNOME terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How can I make Cltr+Alt+T show the terminal that is already open?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1405068/1450948)??

Comment: @Ajay thanks I did not see that. It seems there aren't any Wayland solutions, except running a GNOME extension. For security reasons I prefer not to run any GNOME extensions, but is there another way?

Comment: The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1407162/1450948) of the OP in the question uses a script to achieve the same irrespective of whether it is Wayland or not. You can try it out and if it doesn't work, kindly let me know.

Comment: alt+tab keyboard keys

Comment: @Ajay the scripts all require the use of xdotool and xdotool does not function under Wayland, I can try something like `xdotool type "Do you work in Wayland"` and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you mention the Gnome version in the question??