# terra terminal for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtual-terminal

I would like to try the terra terminal but the ppa doesn't work for 14.04.  Does terra support 14.04?

If so, where can I find it?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, you don't want to go there yet. Lots of bug reports under Ubuntu and Unity. For example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/terra/+bug/1246726 What specific features are you looking for that make you want to use terra? -Rick

Comment: The projects appears to be dead since March 2013. https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ozcanesen/terra/trunk/files

Answer (score 6):

You can make it work under Ubuntu 13.10 and greater. 
First You have to manually download the package for Raring version from here: 
[Terra PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ozcanesen/+archive/ubuntu/terra-terminal/+packages).

Then, install the package with

```
sudo dpkg -i terra_0.1.7~raring1_amd64.deb
```

Then comment the lines 152, 156 and 165-166 in the file

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terra/VteObject.py
```

Here is how that portion of `VteObject.py` looks:

```py
    #self.vte.set_background_saturation(ConfigManager.get_conf('transparency') / 100.0)

    self.vte.set_opacity(int((100 - ConfigManager.get_conf(('transparency'))) / 100.0 * 65535))

    #self.vte.set_background_transparent(ConfigManager.use_fake_transparency)

    self.vte.set_word_chars(ConfigManager.get_conf('select-by-word'))

    self.vte.set_colors(
        Gdk.color_parse(ConfigManager.get_conf('color-text')),
        Gdk.color_parse(ConfigManager.get_conf('color-background')),
        [])

    #self.vte.set_background_image_file(
    #    ConfigManager.get_conf('background-image'))
```

Terra will work after this, but you will not be able to adjust the transparency or set a custom background.

---

As per [mario947's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/711989/284690), adding the following to line 473 of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/terra/terminal.py` will allow you to adjust the transparency. You will need to restart the terminal process every time you adjust the transparency to see your change, however.

```py
self.set_opacity((ConfigManager.get_conf('transparency')) / 100.0)
```

The surrounding part of that file should look like:

```py
def init_transparency(self):
    self.set_app_paintable(True)
    visual = self.screen.get_rgba_visual()
    if visual != None and self.screen.is_composited():
        self.set_opacity((ConfigManager.get_conf('transparency')) / 100.0)
        self.set_visual(visual)
    else:
        ConfigManager.use_fake_transparency = True
```

Comment: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/terra/VteObject.py   ---- same on 14.04 ----
and same lines need #

Comment: get sure that gtk 3.0 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

To make terra transparent in 14.04 you can add this

```
self.set_opacity((ConfigManager.get_conf('transparency')) / 100.0)
```

to the **#473** line of `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/terra/terminal.py`:

```
def init_transparency(self):
    self.set_app_paintable(True)
    visual = self.screen.get_rgba_visual()
    if visual != None and self.screen.is_composited():
        self.set_opacity((ConfigManager.get_conf('transparency')) / 100.0)
        self.set_visual(visual)
    else:
        ConfigManager.use_fake_transparency = True
```