# Can I duplicate a GNOME terminal session?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Often I would like to open a new terminal in the directory i'm currently working in.
E.g. I'm working in ~/some/folder/ and I want to run some program, while at the same time keep a terminal at my disposal in the current directory.

Is there some way I can duplicate the current terminal, by some command or maybe a key combination?

Comment: In my experience, new tabs retain the current working directory in both GNOME Terminal and Terminator. Is a new window necessary or will a tab do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quake-style terminal with splitting in Gnome other than Yakuake](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119095/quake-style-terminal-with-splitting-in-gnome-other-than-yakuake)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

This will open a new tab in GNOME Terminal with same directory(PWD)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

This will open a new window of GNOME Terminal with same directory(PWD)

Comment: I was unaware of both commands (and of the tabbed functionality of the terminal as a whole). This works for me, thanks!

Comment: This stopped working when I upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Answer (score 4):

You can open a second terminal in the same directory using the following command:

```
nohup gnome-terminal --working-directory $PWD >&/dev/null
```

And create an [alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) to quickly get it:

```
alias dupterm='nohup gnome-terminal --working-directory $PWD >&/dev/null'
```

You can have the same result with the following keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: This creates bogus nohub.out files in the current directory whenever you launch it.

Comment: @jmiserez: I fixed the nohup.out issue. But I disagree, it does not block the current terminal, both are still usable

Comment: Try running it from e.g. `terminator`. But I'll give you that it does work now, and it doesn't use keyboard shortcuts which could be nice.

Comment: @jmiserez the context is different from OP, try `nohup gnome-terminal --working-directory $PWD >&/dev/null &` in your case

Comment: I removed the downvote and added an upvote. The only advantage over Ctrl-Shift-N here is that you can type it from the terminal, which I have to say is quite nice.

Comment: @jmiserez: Thanks for your test with terminator btw