# How to duplicate a terminal session at same directory and get root user by default

Tags: command-line, root

I have to duplicate the terminal session at same directory. I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534013/can-i-duplicate-a-gnome-terminal-session#answer-534025). It is working.

But my case is little bit different. If I am already a root user then duplicating terminal is shifting me to normal user at same directory. **I want duplicated terminal with same root user at same directory where I was already.**

Just root user is needed by default on new duplicated terminal at same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just launch a new terminal. The default terminal on Ubuntu is `gnome-terminal`. If you  launch a new one, it will start as the user who launched it and in the directory it was launched from.

So, if you're already logged in as root and are visiting, for example, `/etc`, you can run `gnome-terminal &` (the `&` is just to send it to the background) and a new terminal will appear, running as `root` and in `/etc`.

Comment: I am already using terminal as root and by using these commands, Ctr + Shift + T or Ctrl + Shift + N, it is not creating new terminal as root but it is creating new terminal as default user. Is there some other command?

Comment: @HammadHassan I didn't say you should use Ctrl_Shift+T or +N, I said you should run `gnome-terminal`. So, from the open shell session, run `gnome-terminal &` (the `&` is just to send it to the background) and a new terminal will appear.

Comment: Working. Is there any way that I launch these type of terminals in tabs mode? I want to avoid from new window.

Comment: @HammadHassan not as far as I know, sorry.