# Change default path of Shift+F7 to PWD?

Tags: byobu

My intention is to copy many pages of my terminal output to a file for logging purpose. The trick to [copy screen content](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37455/how-to-copy-command-console-text) does not work well with me. It requires too many keys to remember, and even if I remember it, it is still slower than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to capture the whole thing.

However, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> opens a new window tab name "PRINTSCREEN*" using my environment `$EDITOR`, and if I choose to save it (using vim or emacs), it will save to something like `/tmp/shm/byobu-username-RanDomNameDir/`.

I will have to navigate to my `$PWD` to save the file. The path is most of the time very deep and long. Is there a way I can change so that the temporary buffer of byobu's `PRINTSCREEN` default to `$PWD`?

**Update:**

Why not just use redirection?

Many suggested this. The answer is, I know about redirection. But this is not the case to use it. I do interactive with the terminal to explore various direction before script the work and redirect output to file "properly". My question is about tweaking configuration of byobu's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> command. The sole purpose of it is to serve the use cases where screen redirection did not happen. So no need to talk about screen redirection please.

Comment: Doesn't the `PrtScrn` key work for you?

Comment: @Jos: No, because I have thousands of lines, and want to save the output in text.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want to capture the output of a command (series) you can use [output redirection](/q/420981/175814).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I updated the title to make it clearer what I want to achieve. It is not screen redirection because I want to save my interactive session. It 's not duplicate neither, because the main thing is to change default path for byobu `Shift+F7` command

Comment: @biocyberman: In that case could you please describe how you configured the keyboard short-cut in question in byobu currently (maybe linking to a relevant answer serving as a template)? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I did not customized the shortcut. It is configured by default.  I actually I digged into the source code and found the relevant line: https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/master/usr/share/byobu/keybindings/f-keys.tmux#L65 I will make changes and see

Answer (score 1):

Use Linux embedded `script` utility. For example, to capture everything from terminal to file `capture.log` in the current directory (get it with `pwd`), do:

```
script capture.log
```

To stop capturing just type `exit` or press `CTRL+D`.
More information on `script` and its options:

```
man script
```

**Remark.** Script utility output files contain raw control characters, thus to read it use `less` with `-r` and `-R` options, i.e.

```
less -rR capture.log
```

To clean output files from raw control characters use the command:

```
cat capture.log | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > capture-clean.log
```

The last command removes raw control chars from `capture.log` file and creates plain text file `capture-clean.log`.

Additionally read [How to clean up output of linux 'script' command](https://superuser.com/questions/236930/how-to-clean-up-output-of-linux-script-command).

Comment: I overlooked `script`. It is useful and can almost provide what I want. But, its intention is to print out its output, not to read with plain-text viewers. So it's output looks quite messy if view in, for example, `less`.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I decided that it's best to fix from the root: not `byobu`, but `tmux`. Some nice developer at `tmux` community made a patch. And things works perfectly now: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/1400