# How do I integrate Byobu's copy-buffer with the X clipboard, with text containing quotes?

Tags: byobu

The same as this question, however I'm looking for an answer that would work with text containing quotes.

[How do I integrate Byobu's copy-buffer with the X clipboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33789/how-do-i-integrate-byobus-copy-buffer-with-the-x-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i
```

That copies the tmux clipboard into the X clipboard. The other way round is:

```
xclip -o | tmux load-buffer -
```

This, of course, relies on using tmux as the byobu backend. And I'd like a way for at least the first half to happen automatically whenever I select something in byobu.